# Double to Decimal in MathNet

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Taking notes from my previous question,I created few function that return double.

```
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal[] values = new[] { 39.99m, 29.99m, 19.99m, 49.99m };
        Tuple<double, double> meanStd = values
            .Select(x => (double)x)
            .MeanStandardDeviation();

        double mean = meanStd.Item1;
        double std = meanStd.Item2;

        Console.WriteLine("Mean = " + mean);
        Console.WriteLine("Std = " + std);
    }
}
```

I have to use MathNet library.

**Question**-The output i am getting is double but i am need Decimal.
I am using Convert.toDouble(std) .Will I use some data?How i can avoid this .
Is it possible to get decimal output using MathNet.

Thanks
P.S. -This is simple code,I am creating numerous utility methods using MathNet ,all returning double.

Comment: If Math.NET deals with doubles then you cannot get it to deal with decimals.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. MathNet  library deals with double as per my knowledge so I am waiting for some expert on MathNet (from MIT) lib .

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680907/why-is-system-math-and-for-example-mathnet-numerics-based-on-double

Comment: If there are no overloads that deal with decimals then you'll either have to use doubles, find some other library, fork mathnet and change what it does or write the code yourself.  You can't trick code that deals with doubles to deal with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no overloads that deal with decimals then you'll either have to use doubles, find some other library, fork mathnet and change what it does or write the code yourself. You can't trick code that deals with doubles to deal with decimals - By experts advice given in above comments.

Comment: Please write a question that contains the details - don't ask people to read the "above comments". Answers must be stand-alone.

Comment: Actually i do not want to take the credit .Its my question but i got the answer in comments so I asked to read comments. Appologies.made the changes